# Calculating the largest side of a 3d object - MySQL function to select second greatest value

Tags: mysql, math, cubes

I have three fields for width, height and depth. Let's say I have these values

```
width = 5
height = 0.1
depth = 3
```

I would like to filter out greatest two values from these values and do maths for two dimensions to find out the largest side.

It should be `a * b`

```
a = GREATEST(width, height, depth) /* greatest value selected */
b = GREATEST(width, height, depth) /* <-- select the second greatest value here */
```

The reason why I can't ignore `width` here is that I don't know which one of the `width`, `height`, `depth` has the max value and selected as the value of `a`

EDIT: Didn't mention that these fields may contain `NULL` values

EDIT: The table contains dimensions for 2D objects to. In some cases `depth` may not exist. It can be `NULL`

Comment: If it is a cube, shouldt all sides be the same length?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I will change the title

Comment: Are these columns in the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the types are `float`, you may get rounding errors with this:

```
a = GREATEST(width, height, depth)   /* greatest value selected */
c = LEAST(width, height, depth)
b = width + height + depth - a - c   /* middle value */
```

Another route:

```
b = ( SELECT width AS side
      FROM tableX
      WHERE pk = externalTable.pk
    UNION ALL
      SELECT height
      FROM tableX
      WHERE pk = externalTable.pk
    UNION ALL
      SELECT depth
      FROM tableX
      WHERE pk = externalTable.pk
    ORDER BY side DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
    )
```

Comment: `GREATEST()` and `LEAST()` will not work correctly with Nulls.

Comment: The formula above doesn't work with NULL values. `IFNULL` is not the solution as I thought.

Comment: Well, it depends what you want to do when there nulls. What if there is one null? What if 2 nulls?

Comment: Although I don't think a box with a side of null length is possible :)

Comment: For the 2D cases, are all the Nulls in the same column?